# How to Extract Samples from a Specific Subtree in DecisionTreeRegressor?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

Suppose I want to get the first left child node tree with depth of 1 substree from the resulting decision regression tree. How to accomplish this?

An example of such extraction is depicted here [image: extract subtree]

From what I notice in [DecisionTreeRegressor's documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html), there are no methods allowing such extraction but rather all what is allowed is [to get decision paths](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.decision_path) and to browse according to those paths (to potentially obtain the involved node samples)

Comment: What exactly do you want?; the question title mentions getting the samples (from the training set?), but that's not mentioned in the question body, where it seems to me you want something more about the tree structure?

Comment: I want the samples in the subtree

Comment: So basically you want all samples which passed the root node of the subtree, correct?

Comment: and which are delimited by the subtree yes

Comment: @SSSOF I don't understand the requirement in your last comment. Can you provide an example with your expected output? How should one sample with x[4]=0, and x[5]=1 look like?

Comment: Please help us so that we can help you.